# Change date format in responsebody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, date-format

I have a spring application with a requestmapping that returns a list of Accounts in json.
The Account class has a Date property. This property is returned as a unix timestamp in the json output.

Is there a way to change the dateformat to a  predefined format instead of returning it as a unix timestamp?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userAccounts.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Account> userAccounts() {
            ArrayList<Account> accounts = accountService.getAllUserAccounts(user);
            return accounts;
        }
```

Comment: See: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate

Comment: I'm looking for a more global solution like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038005/spring-3-1-json-date-format I have tried that solution but with no effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685043/java-ee-what-is-the-correct-layer-for-formatting-domain-model-objects-before-p/6687472#6687472

Answer (score 0):

Take the timestamp from your JSON feed and convert in your JSP file.
You can do that using javascript: [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)